# giving a player another turn when landing on a square

Tags: c#

I have this board game I am making. All tokens move when I roll the dice once. If they land on certain squares, they win money and have another turn. I can add the money but not yet let the player on that square have another turn. I have not quite got the code right, can anyone please give suggestions? thanks.

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Rolls the two dice to determine 
    ///     the number of squares to move forward; and
    ///     moves the player's location along the board; and
    ///     obtains the effect of landing on their final square.
    /// Pre:  dice are initialised
    /// Post: the player is moved along the board and the effect
    ///     of the location the player landed on is applied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d1">first die</param>
    /// <param name="d2">second die</param>

    public void Play(Die d1, Die d2) {
        int squares = 0;
        //roll the two given dice
        d1.Roll();
        d2.Roll();
        // get the values on the dice
        // add the values togeather into an int

        squares = d1.FaceValue + d2.FaceValue;
        // move the player that many squares forward
        Move(squares);

        //after move, we need to check the final square to win/loose points
        if (location.Number % 10 == 0)
            location.LandOn(this);

        else if (location.Number % 5 == 0)
            location.LandOn(this);
```

any help appreciated thanks.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SharedGameClasses {
/// <summary>
/// A Ordinary square as well as being the superclass
///  for a Bad Investment Square and a Lottery Win Square
/// </summary>
public class Square {

    // This square's number.
    private int number;
    public int Number {
        get {
            return number;
        }
    }

    // The name of this square. 
    // This is the ‘type’ of square it is: Ordinary, Start, Finish, Lottery Win or 
    Bad Investment.
    private string name;
    public string Name {
        get {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private Board board;  // A reference to the board that contains this square.

    public Square NextSquare {
        get {
            Debug.Assert (Number < Board.FINISH_SQUARE_NUMBER, "Number 
    <Board.FINISH_SQUARE_NUMBER", 
                "The Finish square is the last square.");
            return board.Squares[Number + 1];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless constructor.
    /// Do not want the generic default constructor to be used
    /// as there is no way to set the square's data.
    /// This replaces the compiler's generic default constructor.
    /// Pre:  none
    /// Post: ALWAYS throws an ArgumentException.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>NOT TO BE USED!</remarks>
    public Square() {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameterless constructor invalid.");
    } // end Square constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with initialisation parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">name for this square</param>
    /// <param name="number">number for this square</param>
    public Square(Board board, int number, string name) {
        this.board = board;
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    } // end Square constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the necessary action when a player lands on this type of square.
    /// 
    /// Landing on an ordinary square has
    ///    no consequential action to be performed at this time.
    ///    
    /// Pre:  the player who lands on this square
    /// Post: none.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="player">who landed on this square</param>
    /// <remarks>Virtual method</remarks>
    public virtual void LandOn(Player player) {
        // This method is implemented within subclasses of Square
        // perhaps something will be done in a future version of this game
        // for an Ordinary square
    } //end LandOn

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a square is the Start square.
    /// Pre:  an initialised square location to check
    /// Post: whether the supplied location is the Start square.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the square is the Start square,
    /// false otherwise
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsStart() {
        // check whether the location is the Start square.
        return (number == Board.START_SQUARE_NUMBER);
    } //end IsStart

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a square is the Finish square.
    /// Pre:  an initialised square location to check
    /// Post: whether the supplied location is the Finish square.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the square is the Finish square,
    /// false otherwise
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsFinish() {
        return (number == Board.FINISH_SQUARE_NUMBER);

        // check if the square is a Finish square.
    } // end IsFinish
    }
```

Here is the play code:
                       using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Diagnostics;

```
namespace SharedGameClasses {
/// <summary>
/// Models a player who is currently located on a particular square 
/// with a certain amount of money.
/// </summary>
public class Player {

    private const int INITIAL_AMOUNT = 100;
    private Color randomColor = new Color();

    // name of the player
    private string name;
    public string Name {
        get {
            return name;
        }
        set {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    // amount of money owned by player
    private int money;
    public int Money {
        get {
            return money;
        }
        set {
            money = value;
        }
    }

    // current square that player is on
    private Square location; 
    public Square Location {
        get {
            return location;
        }
        set {
            location = value;
        }
    }

    // whether the player is a winner, in the current game.
    private bool winner;
    public bool Winner {
        get {
            return winner;
        }
        set {
            winner = value;
        }
    }

    private bool finished;
    public bool Finished
    {
        get
        {
            return finished;
        }
        set
        {
            finished = value;
        }
    }

    // PlayerTokenColour and PlayerTokenImage provide colours for the players' 
    tokens    (or "pieces"). 
    // These are not used in the Console version of the game, but will be important 
    in the GUI version.
    private Brush playerTokenColour;
    public Brush PlayerTokenColour
    {
        get { return playerTokenColour; }
        set
        {
            playerTokenColour = value;
            playerTokenImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(PlayerTokenImage))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(playerTokenColour, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private Image playerTokenImage;
    public Image PlayerTokenImage {
        get {
            return playerTokenImage;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a randomly-chosen colour.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A random colour</returns>
    public Color GenerateARandomColour(Random randomNumber)
    {
        const int HIGHEST_COLOUR_VALUE = 255;
        int red = randomNumber.Next(0, HIGHEST_COLOUR_VALUE);
        int green = randomNumber.Next(0, HIGHEST_COLOUR_VALUE);
        int blue = randomNumber.Next(0, HIGHEST_COLOUR_VALUE);
        Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
        return randomColor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless constructor.
    /// Do not want the generic default constructor to be used
    /// as there is no way to set the player's name.
    /// This replaces the compiler's generic default constructor.
    /// Pre:  none
    /// Post: ALWAYS throws an ArgumentException.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>NOT TO BE USED!</remarks>
    public Player() {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameterless constructor invalid.");
    } // end Player constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with initialising parameters.
    /// Pre:  name to be used for this player.
    /// Post: initialised object with random color
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name for this player</param>
    public Player(String name, Square initialLocation) {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        this.name = name;
        this.location = initialLocation;
        this.randomColor = GenerateARandomColour(randomNumber);
        this.PlayerTokenColour = new SolidBrush(this.randomColor);

    } // end Player constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Rolls the two dice to determine 
    ///     the number of squares to move forward; and
    ///     moves the player's location along the board; and
    ///     obtains the effect of landing on their final square.
    /// Pre:  dice are initialised
    /// Post: the player is moved along the board and the effect
    ///     of the location the player landed on is applied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d1">first die</param>
    /// <param name="d2">second die</param>

    public void Play(Die d1, Die d2) {
        int squares = 0;
        //roll the two given dice
        d1.Roll();
        d2.Roll();
        // get the values on the dice
        // add the values togeather into an int

        squares = d1.FaceValue + d2.FaceValue;
        // move the player that many squares forward
        Move(squares);

        //after move, we need to check the final square to win/loose points
        if (location.Number % 10 == 0)
        {
            location.LandOn(this);
            d1.Roll();
            d2.Roll();
            Move(squares);
        }
        else if (location.Number % 5 == 0)
            location.LandOn(this);

    } // end Play.

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves player the required number of squares forward
    /// Pre:  the number of squares to move forward
    /// Post: the player is moved along the board.
    /// NOTE: Refer to Square.cs regarding the NextSquare property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numberOfSquares">the number of squares to move</param>
    private void Move(int numberOfSquares) {
        //create a loop to call nextsquare numberOfSquares times
        while (numberOfSquares > 0)
        {
            if (location.Number ==  Board.FINISH_SQUARE_NUMBER -1)
            {

                Finished = true;
                return;
            }
            location = location.NextSquare;
            numberOfSquares = numberOfSquares - 1;
        }


    } //end Move

    /// <summary>
    /// Increments the player's money by amount
    /// Pre:  amount > 0
    /// Post: the player's money amount is increased.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">increment amount</param>
    public void Credit(int amount) {

        Money = Money + amount;
    } //end Credit

    /// <summary>
    /// Decreases the player's money by amount if 
    ///     the player can afford it; otherwise,
    ///     sets the player's money to 0.
    /// Pre:  amount > 0
    /// Post: player's money is decremented by amount if possible
    ///       but final amount is not below zero
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">decrement amount</param>
    /// 

    public void Debit(int amount)     
        {
            if (money <= 25)
            {
                money = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Money = Money - amount;
            }
         }

     //end Debit
    /// Sets the location of the player (mutator).
    /// Pre:  a square to be used as the player's current location.
    /// Post: sets the player to a location on the board,
    ///     if the location was 'start', the player's amount was also
    ///     reset to the start amount.
    public void ResetToLocation(Square square) {
        if ( square.Number == Board.START_SQUARE_NUMBER){
           Money = 100;
            location = square;
        }
        else
        {
            location = square;
        }
    } //end ResetToStart

 } //end class Player
 }
```

board is set as 6 rows and 7 comlumns

```
          if (location.Number % 10 == 0){
            location.LandOn(this);
            this.Play(d1, d2);}
        else if (location.Number % 5 == 0)
            location.LandOn(this);
```

Comment: What is your criteria for "a certain square"?

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that calls `Play` and controls whose turn it is, too.

Comment: What is the dimension of your board is it 5 by 8 which means let's say 5 rows and 8 columns which makes up 40 squares?

Comment: To add to @Rawling - you need to be keeping the game state somewhere, we can't help figure out how to adjust that if you don't show us where you're storing it and the main function that runs the game.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call recursively Your turn function. If its `Play` function, then add at the end:

```
if(/** criteria for square **/)
    this.Play(d1, d2);
```

And your logics will be executed one more time.

Comment: thanks Kasyx, but I already tried that before and it comes up with an error whenever I get to the top row.

Comment: I dont see where are you calling Play method.

Comment: Do you mean as in the code I have shown above Kasyx? Because I still get errors with that code when all players get to the top row